# How to set System Property "webdriver.gecko.driver" using Robot Framework?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm using the Robot Framework together with the Selenium2Library for automated frontend tests. Usually I ran those tests in Firefox browser. Since version 47 of Firefox the built in FirefoxDriver of the Selenium2Library doesn't work anymore. A searched through the Internet a bit and found, that I have to switch to the Marionette aka. Gecko Driver.

While trying this I get the following error message:

> Suite setup failed: WebDriverException: Message: The path to the
>   driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system
>   property; for more information, see https://github.com/jgraham/wires.
>   The latest version can be downloaded from
>   https://github.com/jgraham/wires

Again I tried to find in the Internet a way to set the path the `GeckoDriver` executable, but I only found a way for Java. Neither for Python nor for the Robot Framework. Does someone have an idea how to set a system property either in Python or in `Robot Framework`?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use Marionette, follow Mukesh's answer and change versions.
If you want to use Marionette, the simplest approach is to add wires (or geckodriver in the future) to the system path as suggested [by the Mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver).

The Python bindings do not support setting the path to GeckoDriver other than by parameter to a webdriver __init__. So if modifying the system path is not an option, the only way forward is to pass the path to your executable into Selenium. From Robot Framework, you can do this with [Create Webdriver](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Create%20Webdriver). The __init__ for Firefox is documented [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver).

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Specifying Path To GeckoDriver
    ${ff default caps}    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].common.desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX    sys,selenium.webdriver
    Set To Dictionary    ${ff default caps}    marionette=${True}
    Create Webdriver    Firefox    executable_path=C:\\stuff\\wires.exe
    Go To    https://stackoverflow.com
    Sleep    2 s
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to resolve the compatibility issue with Firefox 47 and Selenium2Library (which led you to try Marionette/Gecko driver):

Firefox 47 had a bug causing it to crash with selenium webdriver. This bug has been fixed in Firefox 47.0.1 (refer [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/47.0.1/releasenotes/)).

Combination of the latest Selenium2Library (or Selenium 2.53.6) and Firefox 47.0.1 should work fine.

Hope this helps.